# Mapping fields from GraphQL shows error : Next.js GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, next.js

I am trying to map fields with GraphQL in my next.js app, but it returns error.

More info:
I have some GraphQL query, which I already showed in the codes below. The `profile field` has sub categories, I'm trying to map the `profile field` to display all the categories.

Then, I got this error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

My [slug].js:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import { getAllProfilesWithSlug, getProfiles } from '../../lib/api';

export default function Profile({ profileData }) {
    const router = useRouter();

    if (!router.isFallback && !profileData?.slug) {
        return <h1>Error Encountered while getting profile.</h1>;
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title> Profile - {profileData.title} </title>
            </Head>
            <Header />
            <Hero />
            <SideLinks />

            <section className={styles.profile_section}>
                <Container>
                {router.isFallback ? (
                        <h2>Loading...</h2>
                    ) : (
                        <section>
                            <Container>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col lg={6} md={6} sm={6} xs={12}>
                                     {profileData.profiles.map((showProfile) => (
                                       <div key={showProfile.title}>
                                         <h5> {showProfile.profile} </h5>
                                     ))}
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>                  
                            </Container>
                        </section>
                    )}
                </Container>
            </section>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const allProfiles = await getAllProfilesWithSlug();

    return {
        paths: allProfiles.edges.map(({ node }) => `/profile/${node.slug}`) || [],
        fallback: true
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const data = await getProfiles(params.slug);

    return {
        props: {
            profileData: data.businessProfile
        }
    };
}
```

Here's the getAllProfilesWithSlug.js :

```
export async function getAllProfilesWithSlug() {
  const data = await fetchAPI(
    `
    {
      businessProfiles(where: {orderby: {field: DATE, order: ASC}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    `
  );
    return data?.businessProfiles;
}
```

My getProfiles.js file:

```
export async function getProfiles(slug) {
    const data = await fetchAPI(
      `
      fragment BusinessFields on BusinessProfile {
        title
        slug
        businessInfo {
          title
          profiles {
            profile
            profileInfo
          }
          extendedProfile {
            title
            info
          }
         }
        }
      query BusinessProfilesBySlug($id: ID!, $idType: BusinessProfileIdType!) {
        businessProfile(id: $id, idType: $idType) {
          ...BusinessFields
          content
        }
      }
      `,
        {
          variables: {
            id: slug,
            idType: 'SLUG'
          }
        }
    );
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Usually `null` check with `profileData && profileData.profiles && profileData.profiles.map()` solves these type of issues. But I would definitely check if you have any values in `profileData.profiles` because most probably as the error message states it's `undefined`.

Comment: I believe it should be `profileData.businessInfo.profiles.map`?